# How can i make an insert of a SCOPE_IDENTITY() into update in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert an id that i created into an update of each row:

```
    UPDATE TABLE1
    SET NAME=(INSERT INTO TABLE2(EVT01,EVT02) values(0,0)
    SELECT @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY() )
    FROM TABLE1
    INNER JOIN  TABLE2 ON ......
```

How can i make that in SQL Server?

Thanks.

Comment: i suggest break query ...1. insert and 2. than use inserted scope identity to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `Insert Trigger` on Table2 to Update Table1 using `Inserted` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[YourTriggerName]
   ON  [dbo].[Table2]
   AFTER  INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
      UPDATE t1
      SET NAME= t2.IdColName
      FROM Table1 t1
         INNER JOIN  Inserted t2 ON ......

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @NewId  Int

INSERT INTO TABLE2(EVT01,EVT02) values(0,0)

Select  @NewId = @@Identity

UPDATE  t1
SET     t1.NAME = t2.Name
FROM    TABLE1 As t1
        Join TABLE2 As t2 On t1.somecolumn = t2.Id
Where   t2.Id = @NewId
```

***Edit:-***

```
----- Table SourceTable

Insert Into TABLE2(EVT01,EVT02)
Select   Col1
        ,Col2
From    SrouceTable

Update  t1
Set     t1.Name = t2.Id
From    TABLE1 As t1
        Join TABLE2 As t2 On t1.Somecolumn = t2.Id
        Join SourceTable As st On t2.EVT01 = Col1   ----Assumed there would be unique matching column
```

Comment: i want to  create inserts dynamically of the number of  t1.NAME  to update   and insert the @newid into t1.name